# Extremely slow package restores for Azure/Kudu build

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, kudu

We have issues with very long deployment times in Azure/Kudu due to extremely slow package restores for our .NET Core projects. Here is output from the log:

```
2017-05-15T08:33:50.4762761Z,Command: deploy.cmd,,0
2017-05-15T08:33:51.2574560Z,Restoring packages for MySolution.sln,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:16.3007973Z,  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj...,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.6581127Z,  Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\obj\project.assets.json,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.6737370Z,  Restore completed in 6.33 sec for D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj.,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.6737370Z,  ,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.6737370Z,  NuGet Config files used:,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.6908155Z,      D:\local\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.6908155Z,  ,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.7049839Z,  Feeds used:,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.7049839Z,      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:22.7362324Z,Building and publishing MyProject.csproj,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:23.2362247Z,Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:23.2520644Z,Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:23.2520644Z,,,0
2017-05-15T09:12:28.8924730Z,  MyProject -> D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\MyProject.dll,,0
```

As you can see, it takes almost 30 minutes between these steps alone:

```
2017-05-15T08:33:51.2574560Z,Restoring packages for MySolution.sln,,0
2017-05-15T08:59:16.3007973Z,  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj...,,0
```

Help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It doesn't seem to be an issue only with package restore. Here's an example of when the build itself also takes an hour:

```
* 2017-09-06T11:27:45.4325294Z,Restoring packages for MySolution.sln,,0
* 2017-09-06T12:10:47.8765057Z,  Restore completed in 974.85 ms for D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj.,,0
* 2017-09-06T12:10:47.9397198Z,Building and publishing MyProject.csproj,,0
* 2017-09-06T13:09:33.8740387Z,Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core,,0
2017-09-06T13:09:33.8896654Z,Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.,,0
2017-09-06T13:09:33.9052887Z,,,0
2017-09-06T13:29:16.1438980Z,  MyProject -> D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\MyProject.dll,,0
2017-09-06T13:32:51.0677707Z,  MyProject -> D:\local\Temp\8d4f51a4b579642\,,0
```

Nothing fancy is going on in the csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>MyProject</PackageId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="*.ts;app\**\*" />
    <None Update="rewrite-rules.xml">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you able to repro the same if you do a nuget restore manually from Kudu console? That would help isolate from anything directly related to Kudu deployment logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidEbbo. Seems to take a lot of time when restoring manually from the Kudu console as well. Didn't get any timestamps but from what I could tell it was an equal amount of time. What happens between the two steps that I refer to in the post? Package downloads? I have enabled verbose logging but it's still blank between those two steps.

Comment: The idea of running it directly from Kudu Console was to make the details of the deployment script irrelevant. Which specific command did you run from Kudu Console that took a long time? Was it 'nuget restore'?

Comment: I see. I ran "dotnet restore"

Comment: One more thing to try to isolate: is the slowness specific to this one Web App, or would it happen to any in any region. If it's general, can you share a minimal test repo that would allow others to try it?

Comment: Same problem for all our web apps. Are there any known issues with the "dotnet restore" command? Is it possible to enable more verbose logging for that command to see what's going on?

Comment: I'm on the App Service side, so would need a dotnet expert to answer that. But if you share a test repo that repros that, we'll take a look at what's making it so slow in app service.

Comment: Ok, will try to do that when I have some time